How do I use "git stash pop" while maintaining Intellij changelist structure?
I have a working copy in intellij where the changelist structure in commit panel looks like this:
- Changes
   fileA
   fileB
- My_changelist_1
   fileC
   fileD
- My_changelist_2
   fileE

where all files are tracked/staged.
After I use git stash, they are all saved which is fine. But when I use git stash pop or git stash apply to restore them, the structure becomes:
- Changes
   fileA
   fileB
   fileC
   fileD
   fileE
- My_changelist_1
- My_changelist_2
   

so I lost the structure and had to manually put them back into the changelists.
how do I preserve the changelist structure when I stash them?
I have been trying to use git stash --keep-index but I think this will leave out tracked files which is not what I want.

What do you call a changelist here? The "commit structure" you're showing is equally mysterious. Because that's not at all how commits are structured in git.

As far as I know, git has no native concept of a "changelist". Is this structure the view in some particular application you're using? And are you using that same application to create and pop the stash?

This question would be easier for us to answer if you include a [mcve] -- show us actual git commands, along with their output. You don't need to show us your code; you can create an example repository for the purposes of reproducing the issue.

I use intellij to code - I think that's where the concept of "changelist" coming from, and it's predated from integration of git in intellij. Sorry for the confusion, I'll rephrase my question

I think IntelliJ has its own feature called shelving that's similar to stashing. Maybe you can use that? See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/shelving-and-unshelving-changes.html

You could also start to use git worktree when you have to work on something else instead of git stash. Then you wont get this problem at all :P

(As said in the comments)
The change list is a an IntelliJ concept. Not a Git one. And it is not "persisted" across Git operations.
If you want to use change list, you'd better use the shelves concept of IntelliJ which is very similar to Git stash concept but will help you maintain different shelves by names and unshelve them to the desired change list.
